# Unable to use C# COM object from Perl

Tags: c#, perl, com, ole

I'm trying to create a C# COM Object to be used in a Perl script (As far as I understand COM is the best way to go).

Here is the C# code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExampleCom
{
    [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E474F4C3C83F")]
    public interface IComClass
    {

    }

    [Guid("7BD20046-DF8C-44A6-8F6B-687FAA26FA71")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IComClassEvents
    {

    }

    [Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F938")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComClassEvents))]
    [ProgId("ExampleCom.ComClass")]
    public class ComClass : IComClass
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the output of RegAsm:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.0.30319.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can ca
use your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on
the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed
assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.
Types registered successfully
```

And finally, the perl script:

```
use Win32::OLE;
$ex = Win32::OLE->new('ExampleCom.ComClass') or die "oops\n";
print $ex;
```

Unfortunately, every time I run the Perl script I get the output "Oops", so it isn't callable. However, I can successfully instantiate the "Excel.Application" object. I have set the settings "Register for COM interop" and "Make assembly COM-Visible" in the Visual Studio project settings and as mentioned above I have separately used RegAsm to try and register the dll.

Does anyone have experience here they can share, point me in the right direction or advise me of where I'm going wrong please?

Thanks.

Comment: Set `$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3` for `Win32::OLE` to croak on errors (with possibly useful information).

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have a more useful debugging message than oops.  I would suggest writing a vbscript program that would give a more useful message.

Is your version of Perl that you are running 32 or 64 bit?  If it is 64-bit, then your program is failing because in-process servers (DLL OLE servers) have to have the same bit-ness as their clients.  If that is the case, then you need to run the 64-bit version of regasm which will be in the Framework64 directory instead of the Framework directory.

Excel will succeed because it is an out of process server and the bit-ness is not required to match--of course the bit-ness might match.

A simple vbscript program is:

```
Dim obj
Set obj = CreateObject("ExampleCom.ComClass")
MsgBox TypeName(obj)
```

On a 64-bit OS, the standard version of cscript.exe or wscript.exe is a 64-bit program.  You might try running with the 32-bit version with c:\windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe (or cscript.exe).

Comment: It turns out my dll was being built for 32 bit while Perl is 64-bit. Running your script with wscript/cscript in the SysWOW64 folder helped me find that. Thank you and excuse my terrible Perl skills (I'm not a Perl dev lol).